# Visual Studio 2017 - Install Xamarin Forms 3 NuGet package into solution

Tags: xamarin, nuget

I have Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin installed.
I want to update to Xamarin.Forms 3

I understand that I have to use NuGet to install the Xamarin Forms 3 NuGet package.

However, to install to NuGet package I need to open a solution in Visual Studio first.
When I open a solution and install the NuGet package - will this package (Forms 3) only be available for that solution?
I need Forms 3 to be available for all new solutions that I will create in future...

Comment: You can create your own project templates that will use the version of XF that you want, or eventually MS will update the default templates to use the newer version of XF.  But otherwise you will have to manually update your projects to the newer version of XF.

Answer (score 1):

If you have at least Visual Studio 2017 15.7 installed then the latest Cross-Platform project templates provided by Xamarin use the Xamarin.Forms 3.0 NuGet package.

For existing projects you have created you would need to update the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package yourself.